# List files with names that contain alphabetic characters and any other symbols (i.e numbers, punctuation, etc.) and sort them by size

Tags: linux, bash

I need help modifying command i have already written.

That's what i was able to achieve:

```
find -type f -name '*[:alpha:]*' -exec ls -ltu {} \; | sort -k 5 -n -r
```

However, this command also finds filenames that cosist solely of alphabetic characters, so i need to get rid of them too. I have tried doing something like this to the code:

```
find -type f -name '*[:alpha:]*' -and ! -name '[:alpha:]' -exec ls -ltu {} \; | sort -k 5 -n -r
```

But it does nothing. I understand that something is wrong with my name formatting but i have no idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Character classes like `[:alpha:]` may only be used within character range `[..]` expressions, e.g. `[0-9_[:alpha:]]`. They may not be used alone.

`[:alpha:]`  by itself a character range expression equivalent to `[ahlp:]` and matches any of the characters "ahlp" or colons. It does not match alphabetical characters.

To find files that contains both at least one alphabetic and at least one non-alphabetic characters:

```
find dir -type f -name '*[[:alpha:]]*' -name '*[^[:alpha:]]*'
```